# LALR(1) Parser DFA Lookahead Core Question

Tags: parsing, grammar, lalr

I am having trouble understanding what the rules are for adding a lookahead to a core production during the construction of the DFA. To illustrate my confusion, I will be using an online parser generator that exposes all the internal calculations; [this_tool](https://jsmachines.sourceforge.net/machines/lalr1.html). (<- open in a new tab)

(The formating is: `NONTERMINAL -> RULE, LOOKAHEADS`, where the lookaheads are forward slash sperated)

Using this grammar as an example:

```
S -> E
E -> ( E )
E -> N O E
E -> N
N -> 1
N -> 2
N -> 3
O -> +
O -> -
```

Copy and pasting the above grammar into the lalr parser generator will produce a dfa with 12 states (click the `>>`). My question is finally, why are the `goto(0, N)` kernel productions ( `{[E -> N.O E, $/)]; [E -> N., $/)]}` ) initiated with the `)` terminal? Where does the `)` come from? I would expect the `goto(0, N)` to be `{[E -> N.O E, $]; [E -> N., $]}`. Equally the kernel production in the `goto(0, ( )` has an 'extra' `)`.

As the dfa is being constructed, equal cores are merged (the core is the set of productions that introduce a new state by performing closure on that set). State 2 has production `[E -> .N, )];`, which when merged with `[E -> N., $]` produces the correct output, but there's no way for state 0 to have known about lookahead of `)`

Thanks in advance, sorry if this was a confusing and specific question and about using an external website to demonstrate my issue.✌️

Comment: The lookahead isn't used to start the production; it's used to terminate it. (That is, to do a reduction.) Unless the item is a reduction item (with the position indicator, the dot, at the end), the lookahead is just passed through to the successor state. Shift and GOTO actions are triggered by the symbol following the dot, not by the lookahead. Only reduction actions, which have no symbol following the dot, are gated by the lookahead. When a new item is created by closure, it is created with the lookahead set to the FOLLOW of the LHS symbol, which comes into play when the entire RHS matches.

Comment: (It's actually a subset of the FOLLOW set but a comment is too short to be precise.Your textbook has the details.)
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to propagate any newly found lookaheads then 'goto' the states where those lookaheads are cores of.

The method is described in chapter 4 section 7.5 of the Dragon Book 2nd ed.
(here: https://github.com/muthukumarse/books/blob/master/Dragon%20Book%20Compilers%20Principle%20Techniques%20and%20Tools%202nd%20Edtion.pdf)